# Getting error in Python 3.x : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming. I've started with Python 3.x, learning from Python Crash Course. I encountered an error when I was trying an example program in the book. 
Code is:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        car_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model + 'model.'
        return car_name.title()
    def read_odometer(self):
        print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

my_dream_car = Car('lamborghini', 'one-off', 2017 )
print("\nMy dream car is " + my_dream_car.get_descriptive_name())
my_dream_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_dream_car.odometer_reading()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Jai/PycharmProjects/PCC/Chapter_9-Classes/4_car_class.py", line 18, in <module>

My dream car is 2017 Lamborghini One-Off Model.

    my_dream_car.odometer_reading()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of `my_dream_car.odometer_reading` to an integer and then you're calling it:

```
my_dream_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_dream_car.odometer_reading()
```

This is why you're getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` because `int` is not something that you can call.

You probably meant to write:

```
my_dream_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_dream_car.read_odometer()
```